# Sass: add element in front of & 2+ level nest

Tags: sass

Here's my code:

```
.home {
  .chart {
    .profile { // <- I want this one to behave different when it's inside of a table element
      display: block;

      table & { // <- First instinct
        display: flex;
      }

      @at-root table #{&} { // <- Second attempt
        display: flex; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can also do it the long way of just defining a profile again, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Is there another way that works or something that I'm not seeing?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I see now that the `&` in this case represents

```
.home .chart .profile
```

but it really seems like there should be a way to do either

```
.home .chart table .profile
```

or just

```
table .profile
```